# Call function after modal loads angularjs ui bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using `Angularjs UI bootstrap` to render Modal windows in my project. But In some situation I want to call a function after the modal loads. I have tried with `$timeout` and `$viewContentLoaded` but no use. can any one help me to resolve this issue.

Thank you all.

Comment: You mean MODALS?? Im not sure I follow you problem

Comment: can you post some code? for better guidance, I think I've had the same problem before and I solved it. some code can go a long way :3

Comment: thanks @Gabriel Matusevich. I go through the documentation of angular ui bootstrap and I found the solution

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I go through the documentation of angular ui bootstrap and finally I found the solution.

The `open` method returns a `modal instance`, an object with the `opened` propertie:

`opened` - a `promise` that is resolved when a modal gets opened after downloading content's template and resolving all variables

to call function after model opens.

```
$modalInstance.opened.then(function(){
  alert('hi');
});
```

Comment: awesome, that was the problem I had before .. :D i was trying to do something before the promise was resolved .... good to know that you found the solution

Comment: but here handle the opened method from $modelInstance in biggest issue. I am trying to call that method

Comment: the above method call the function on model loading

Comment: If you need to do DOM manipulation and you're waiting for the controller to be loaded *and* rendered, you might be looking for `$modalInstance.rendered.then(...`.

Comment: Can you give me a code snippet for the above solution ? urgent

Comment: Just tried to summarize the useful methods that one may use: var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
 // your code
});
modalInstance.opened.then(function(){
 // your code
});
modalInstance.rendered.then(function(){
 // your code
});
modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedItem) {
 // Returned from popup
}, function() { $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
});

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, you can use:

```
$modalInstance.rendered.then(function(){
  alert('hi');
});
```

*PS: this was originally pointed by @esqew user. I put it here just to be easier to find.*