# Angular modal close function not executing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui.bootstrap

The loading modal is created correctly, but when the finally block is hit it does not close it.  Is there any known reason for this?  The loading time is minimal but I still need it for cases where there is a delay.  I am testing with a device and in Chrome - The issue only arises when it is being run in Chrome.

```
$scope.init = function() {
  var dialog = Modals.openLoadingModal();

  OfflineManager.getTemplates().then(function(templates) {
    $scope.templates = templates.map(function(e) {
      // get e
      return e;
    });

    OfflineManager.getInspections().then(function(inspections) {
      $scope.inspections = inspections.map(function(e) {
        // get e
        return e;
      });
    }).finally(function() {
      dialog.close();
    });
  });
};
```

The modal view:

```
<div class="loadingModal">
  <data-spinner data-ng-init="config={color:'#fff', lines:8}" data-config="config"></spinner>
</div>
```

The modal service:

```
this.openLoadingModal = function(callback) {
  var opts = {
    backdrop: true,
    backdropClick: false,
    keyboard: false,
    templateUrl: 'views/modals/loading.html'
  };
  return this.open(opts, callback, null);
};


this.open = function(opts, closeHandler, dismissHandler, model) {
  opts.resolve = { modalModel:function() { return model; }};
  opts.controller = opts.controller || 'ModalController';

  $('div, input, textarea, select, button').attr('tabindex', -1);

  var modalInstance = $modal.open(opts);
  modalInstance.result.then(function(result) {
    $('div, input, textarea, select, button').removeAttr('tabindex');
    if (closeHandler) {
      closeHandler(result);
    }
  }, function(result) {
    $('div, input, textarea, select, button').removeAttr('tabindex');
    if (dismissHandler) {
      dismissHandler(result);
    }
  });
  return modalInstance;
};
```

Comment: Going to be really hard to diagnose without knowing what implementation of your `Modals` is. Are you using **ui-bootstrap**, some other 3rd party implementation, or is it custom rolled?

Is this something you could put into a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/), or [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @Josh Yes I am using ui-bootstrap version 0.13.4. I can't add it too Plunker or JsFiddle - there is a lot more code behind what I have here.  I will add the html of the modal

Comment: At least post the code of your Modals service - otherwise it is impossible to know what you are returning, how the close() function looks like, etc.

Comment: Stupid question - you have `<data-spinner ...>` but the closing tag is `</spinner>` - is that just a typo?

Comment: @MichaelRose I am not sure, I edited them to match but it makes no difference. I also forgot to say I am testing this on chrome and with an actual device - The issue only appears when running in chrome.

Comment: Mixing JQuery and angular can make debugging really hard...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching I found the following solution which waits until the modal has finished opening before executing:

```
.finally(function() {
    dialog.opened.then(function() {
      dialog.close();        
    });
});
```

Source:
[Call function after modal loads angularjs ui bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24360418/call-function-after-modal-loads-angularjs-ui-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

Per the ui.bootstrap docs - http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/0.13.3/#/modal

> result - a promise that is resolved when a modal is closed and rejected when a modal is dismissed

It looks like you're trying to use the wrong promise to execute your logic.  `result` gets triggered as a product of calling `$modalInstance.close` or `$modalInstance.dismiss`.  If you're trying to close your modal programmatically (as opposed to closing via ng-click within the modal template/controller) you need to call `$modalInstance.close` or `$modalInstance.dismiss` directly, **then** your `result.then` will execute.